# How can I send a text to a logfile given that a certain event has finished within a loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, logging, random-forest, progress

I try to get error rates for different parameter settings for a random forest (classification).
Given that I use a loop and this takes considerable time i would like to know how much time has passed up until a certain point. For this I would like to get a result saved on a logfile each time a certain event has passed. the code looks like this.

```
library(randomForest)

ntree<-c(1:1000)

mtry<-c(1:30)

set.seed(123)

for (j in mtry) {

for (i in ntree) {

  rf1 <- randomForest(mymodel,mtry=j, ntree=i)

  result = data.frame(mtry=j,ntree=i, 
                      OOB=rf1[["err.rate"]][nrow(rf1[["err.rate"]]),"OOB"]) 

  oob_NP = rbind(oob_NP, result)
} 
}
```

I would like to get a result in a log file for every hundred model...So show me the error rate result for

mtry=1, ntree=100

mtry=1, ntree=200

.

.

.

mtry=30,ntree=1000

Anyone an idea how to integrate this in the code?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with `sprintf` to produce the log text lines and `cat` to write them to a connection.

```
logfile <- "Tacatico.log"

ntree <- 1:10
mtry <- 1:3

logfile_con <- file(logfile, open = "wt")
for (j in mtry) {
  for (i in ntree) {
    logtext <- sprintf("mtry=%d    ntree=%d", j, i)
    cat(logtext, '\n', file = logfile_con)
  }
}
close(logfile_con)
```

Check what was written to the log file.

```
readLines(logfile)
# [1] "mtry=1    ntree=1 "  "mtry=1    ntree=2 "  "mtry=1    ntree=3 " 
# [4] "mtry=1    ntree=4 "  "mtry=1    ntree=5 "  "mtry=1    ntree=6 " 
# [7] "mtry=1    ntree=7 "  "mtry=1    ntree=8 "  "mtry=1    ntree=9 " 
#[10] "mtry=1    ntree=10 " "mtry=2    ntree=1 "  "mtry=2    ntree=2 " 
#[13] "mtry=2    ntree=3 "  "mtry=2    ntree=4 "  "mtry=2    ntree=5 " 
#[16] "mtry=2    ntree=6 "  "mtry=2    ntree=7 "  "mtry=2    ntree=8 " 
#[19] "mtry=2    ntree=9 "  "mtry=2    ntree=10 " "mtry=3    ntree=1 " 
#[22] "mtry=3    ntree=2 "  "mtry=3    ntree=3 "  "mtry=3    ntree=4 " 
#[25] "mtry=3    ntree=5 "  "mtry=3    ntree=6 "  "mtry=3    ntree=7 " 
#[28] "mtry=3    ntree=8 "  "mtry=3    ntree=9 "  "mtry=3    ntree=10 "
```